# Consequences for not estimating autocorrelated residuals in a growth curve model

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, curve-fitting, growth-model, mplus

I am fitting a second order growth model with 7 time points on Mplus.
When I estimate the model with autocorrelated residuals in it
the model will not run because of identification issues.
(when I remove the code for autocorrelated residuals it runs,
so it is about sample size, I suppose)
I want to know how not accounting for autocorrelated residuals
will affect the estimation.
Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: Greetings and welcome to CV! It would be helpful to provide a lot more information about what is going on. Giving answerers information about the nature of the data, output from the model, etc. will ensure a higher likelihood of this question getting answered.

Comment: Thank you so much for this advice. I was not sure what would be useful information that will help me get informed answers. I'll educate myself more next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how many indicators per time point you have and how many error covariances you allow (e.g., only between the error terms for corresponding indicators and adjacent time points vs. *all* error correlations for the same variable over time). In my opinion, a better way to account for indicator-specific effects is to include method (indicator-specific) factors; specifically, one residual method factor less than there are indicators. This often leads to a more parsimonious specification and a clearer interpretation of the results. See Figure 2 in the following paper:

Eid, M., Schneider, C., & Schwenkmezger, P. (1999). Do you feel better or worse? The validity of perceived deviations of mood states from mood traits. *European Journal of Personality, 13*(4), 283-306.

Or (perhaps even better) use indicator-specific growth factors (and no error covariances or method factors at all). See

Bishop, J., Geiser, C., & Cole, D. A. (2015). Modeling latent growth with multiple indicators: A comparison of three approaches. *Psychological Methods*, *20*(1), 43-62.

Eid, M., Courvoisier, D. S., & Lischetzke, T. (2012). Structural equation modeling of ambulatory assessment data. In M. R. Mehl & T. S. Connor (Eds.), *Handbook of research methods for studying daily life* (pp. 384–406). New York, NY: Guilford Press.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Geiser for answering my question in great detail! You answer helped me understand my question and at the same time educated me as to what kind of information to include when asking questions on CrossValidated next time! I'll read through the articles you have provided me. Thanks again. It really helped.